# Is there a way to emulate vt52 or any other terminal type in linux just like xterm?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, linux-terminal, terminal-emulator

I am just asking (for curiosity) whether there exist other terminal emulators in linux/ubuntu that understand escape sequence's for other terminal types (just like gnome-terminal does for xterm), vt52 for example.

I did try setting $TERM=vt52 but it goes nuts so I don't think gnome-terminal does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell your xterm to simulate a VT52, and you need to tell your environment that you run a VT52. So use **`xterm -ti vt52 -tn vt52`**. The first parameter sets up VT52 emulation, the second parameter sets up $TERM in the virtual environment (it is a *virtual* terminal, after all).

On my system, this is enough to make "clear" work in a VT52 emulation.

Answer (score 1):

xterm emulates a VT-100 (higher level, but ok).

VT-100 has VT-52 mode: Sending the sequence

ESC [?2l   (in hex: 1b 5b 3f 6c)

will cause a VT-100 (and xterm) to enter VT-52 mode.
To return to VT-100 (ANSI) mode:

ESC <  (1b 3c)

but... note that MOST terminal emulators are not VT-100 compatible, and do not do this correctly -- the VT-100 does, and xterm does.

xterm does VT-100 (and many VT-XXX) and TEK 4010 (vector graphics). If set to VT-340, it does sixel graphics as well.